# How to get Visual Studio to run on a git commit point in history

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to run on a git commit point in history?

I encounter a JavaScript error when running a ASP.NET Core site on Visual Studio 2022. Unfortunately the nature of the error does not tell me why that error occurs. To troubleshoot, I want to locate the commit point that introduced the error.

So, is there a way for Visual Studio to run on any specific commit point in history? I'm fairly new to Git, and Git in Visual Studio. Thank you.

Comment: You can checkout to specific commit using visual studio git toolbox or git checkout command in terminal and then run application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to checkout a commit and examine that for error.

You can do this by first running `git log` to get a list of your commits and their hashes on the branch:

```
git log
----

commit 53f54789f494f44b3001dccc2f0f7a000da1ae10 (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
Author: some_user (someuser@email.com)       
Date:   Thu Aug 17 02:51:10 2023 -0400

    commit # 2 -- maybe this one has error

commit c5458fda666923cd16b8518bbf2991a52bdf7910
Author: some_user (someuser@email.com)        
Date:   Wed Aug 16 22:20:08 2023 -0400

    commit # 1
```

Then you can use `git checkout <commit hash>` to check:

```
git checkout 53f54789f494f44b3001dccc2f0f7a000da1ae10
```

If you then end up finding the error in that commit, you can create a new branch off that commit.

Comment: If I check out a specific commit, is the code base in Visual Studio the code base in that commit? And if so, after checking out that particular commit, identify and fix the error, how do I go back to  the most current code base (instead of the one in history)?

Comment: Yes. After 'checking in' to the respective commit, VsCode will reflect the file structure to correspond to the files structure present in that commit.

To go back to the most current code base (assuming you only viewed the previous commit without making any changes), you can simply use `git commit <branch-name>`

I also recommend reading this book from Git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Were you able to try it? @Luan